# php variable in javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, variables

Why is my Javascript array empty?
In a while loop I fill a variable ($btext). When I echo $btext everything is shown fine:

But if I try to fill the Javascript array nothing is printed there.

This is how I fill the variable $btext in php:

```
$btext .= "\"".${'name_'.$user}."\",";
```

Here the Javascript part:

```
var battletext = new Array(<? echo $btext; ?>);
```

If I define $btext like:

```
$btext = "\"Hallo\", \"Welt\"";
```

the Sourcecode looks like this:

```
<script>
var battletext = new Array("Hallo", "Welt");
</script>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what your problem is from this question.

Comment: Why do you think it would be empty? battletext has a length of 2.

Comment: Where's the empty array?

Comment: the emty array in JS looks like this: new Array()

Comment: Try `$btext = array(); $btext[] = ${'name_'.$user}; echo "var battletext = ".json_encode($btext).";";`

Answer (score 6):

You should just use json encode:

```
$battletext = array( "Hallo", "Welt" );
```

html:

```
<script>
var battletext = <?php echo json_encode( $battletext ); ?>;
</script>
```

source:

```
<script>
var battletext = ["Hallo", "Welt"];
</script>
```

Comment: How can I fill the $battletext in a while loop?

Comment: To explain what i like to do: I like to fill in the loop a variable ($btext) and later the JS should step through every part of the variable and show this in a textbox

Comment: @Quicknation Instead of string concatenation in your loop (`$btext .= `) declare `$btext = array()` before the loop, and inside the loop use this line: `$btext[] = ${'name_'.$user};` - then you have a PHP array of all the names, which `json_encode()` will translate to a valid Javascript [array literal](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/literal-notation.shtml). As a side note, you would do better to use an array in the first place instead of variable variable names

Comment: @DaveRandom: I did it like you discribed. In the source code there is still an empty array: var battletext = <? echo json_encode($btext); ?>; if I echo $btext[1] the name is shown...???

Comment: what happens if you do `<? print_r($btext); ?>` in the same place in the code?

Comment: The result is: var battletext = Array(); (in sourcecode) While using this: var battletext = <? print_r($btext); ?>; (in the script)... This: echo"!!!".$btext[1]."!!!"; returns the right name...???